# How to remove Markers in Angular2 google maps

Tags: google-maps, angular

Can any one help me how to remove markers in sebm google maps in angular2 google maps? It is working when I set the visibility of the marker to false. It made the marker to hide. But I need to remove the entire marker from the marker array.

> app.component.html

```
<sebm-google-map  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)">
 <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let m of markers" [latitude]= 'm.lat' [longitude]='m.lng'  [visible]='m.visible' (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m)" [iconUrl]='m.iconUrl' [label]="">
  <sebm-google-map-info-window>
   <p>info window</p>
  </sebm-google-map-info-window>
 </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

> app.component.ts

```
this.markers.push(
{
 id: m.perma_link,
 title: null,
 isOpen: false,
 lat: parseFloat(m.latitude),
 lng: parseFloat(m.longitude),
 label: m.event_name,
 address: m.address,
 mobile: parseFloat(m.mobile),
 phone: m.phone,
 visible: true,
 image: img_result,
 iconUrl: 'events.png'
})
```

Comment: provide your html code

Comment: made changes and added my html code

Comment: That's not the code they're looking for....post all the html map related code and the component code(just marker related).

Comment: you have to achieve this using back end by calling api's

Comment: but how to remove the data from the markers array

Comment: no need to remove. you call api's on some event you will get new data. it will be updated automatically

Comment: If I do this the new data is appending to the old data and array size of markers size is increasing

Answer (score 0):

Empty Array

```
this.markers = [];
```

sort array via filter

```
  this.markers.filter( (markers) => {
    return markers.id !== 2;
    }
)
```

Return a new array without a marker with id of 2.

I usually just set visibility to either true or false to hide markers instead of remove them from array.

Comment: I tried to set the visibility to be true or false. But I need to remove the marker data completely from the markers array.